# Qt ignores CSS in QTextDocument

Tags: qt, qtextedit, qtextdocument, qtextcursor

Here is a small snippet of my code, I don't know why but Qt is ignoring the css.

```
QTextDocument *mTextDocument = new QTextDocument(0);
QTextEdit *textEdit = new QTextEdit(0);
mTextDocument->setDefaultStyleSheet(QString::fromUtf8("body{background-color: rgb(0,111,200);}"));
QTextCursor *_cursor = new QTextCursor(mTextDocument);
textEdit->setDocument(mTextDocument);
_cursor->insertBlock();
_cursor->insertHtml("<html><body><p>Hello world</p></body></html>");
textEdit->show();
```

I'm using Qt 4.8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your document already has `html` and `body` tags, so they are simply ignored when they are found in `insertHtml`.

If you were using `QTextEdit::setHtml`, they would be new elements and the default stylesheet would be applied to them.