# Apply a custom stylesheet to QTextDocument

Tags: c++, qt

I want to apply some custom stylesheet to a QTextDocument using `setDefaultStyleSheet` function, however it get ignored.
According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15730224/qt-ignores-css-in-qtextdocument) post i should add the style sheet *after* setting the html content, but this did not solve my problem.
My code:

```
QString *html = new QString();
*html = "<tr>" + name + "</tr>"
        "<tr>" + surname + "</tr>"
        "<tr>" + age + "</tr></table>";
QTextDocument doc;
doc.setHtml(*html);
doc.setDefaultStyleSheet("table { border: 1px solid black; }"); // This should apply the style sheet
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is with the `table` property `border` (not to be confused with the CSS shorthand) must be set to a value greater than or equal to 1 otherwise no border will be displayed. Consider this code:

```
QString *html = new QString();
*html = "<table border = 1> <tr>" + name + "</tr>"
    "<tr>" + surname + "</tr>"
    "<tr>" + age + "</tr></table>";
QTextDocument doc;
doc.setDefaultStyleSheet("table { border: 1px solid black}");
doc.setHtml(*html);
```

---

Additionally, you mention in your answer that you have to add the style sheet *after* the setting the html, however the [docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextdocument.html#defaultStyleSheet-prop) for `QTextDocument` seem to indicate otherwise:

> The default style sheet is applied to all newly HTML formatted text that is inserted >into the document, for example using setHtml() or QTextCursor::insertHtml().

hence why `setDefaultStylesheet()` is *before* `setHtml()` in the above code.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, it works now! However i am not able to do the same thing with `border-collapse`, but i think it's a problem with Qt(they probably haven't implemented it yet)

Comment: I expect so, since that isn't listed in the [Supported HTML Subset](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/richtext-html-subset.html) for `table`. I'm glad this answer helped - don't forget to accept it if it solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

You can also add the styling information into a `<style>` tag inside the HTML document. This works as of Qt 5.12, but seems to be undocumented behavior (at least `style` is not mentioned in the [list of supported tags](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/richtext-html-subset.html#supported-tags)).

Your code would then be:

```
QString *html = new QString();
*html = "<html>"
        "  <head><style>table { border: 1px solid black; }</style></head>"
        "  <body>"
        "    <table border = 1>"
        "      <tr>" + name + "</tr>"
        "      <tr>" + surname + "</tr>"
        "      <tr>" + age + "</tr>"
        "    </table>"
        "  </body>"
        "</html>";
QTextDocument doc;
doc.setHtml(*html);
```

(Actually, I tested this only with the Qt QML Text element. But since it maps to QTextDocument internally, I'm pretty sure this also applies to QTextDocument itself. Apologies if not.)